# basicnamevaluepairs with arraylist

Tags: android

Hi I want to post a ArrayList with the namevaluepairs from my androidapp.

It seems that the only way to this is to post a String. Whats the solution?

```
public JsonUpdateBrands(ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds, String userid,
        String webpage) {
    super();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();       
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serviceId", selectedIds));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userid));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "Subscription"));

    progress(nameValuePairs, webpage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialized the list of objects into a String and you're good to go.

Maybe a JSON String would be a good idea.  Jackson is a terrific Java-to-JSON serializer.  Give it a look.

Comment: Hmm, ive never used that. Do you have an example? :)

Comment: I know their web site does.  Why not go there, download it, and try it?